# Refreshing Title of UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm stuck on this one.

I have my app load of a modal view which is a navigation controller initiated with a table view controller. I have no trouble setting the title on the nav controller bar initially before the form loads.

But once the modal view is loaded, is there anyways to update/refresh the title if I wanted to change it?

Eg: each row has a random number as it's text and also a UISwitch. When I set the switch to on. I want the title to update to the sum of all the random numbers.

ei: (i know this isn't correct)

`navController.title = @"Sum=25";`

```
navControler.title.update;
```

Thanks guys.
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Setting self.title should do it.

Comment: Thanks Nick. After you told me that I found out what the real problem was.